# Error when using ajax from domain other

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

In host1 with domain http://domain1 I am using ajax with structure:

1. index.php (that is include ajax)
2. config.php (connect database)
3. get_city.php

code here:

```
index.php
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.nation').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+id;
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '**http://domain1/get_data.php**',
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(html) {
                $('.city').html(html);
           } 
        });
   });
});
```

in get_city.php:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
if($id) {
    $query = mysql_query("Select * From  jos_city Where nation_id = id");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['city_name'];
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
}
```

When I use the other host with domain http://domain2, then ajax can't load

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.nation').change(function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id='+id;
            $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '**http://domain1/get_data.php**',
               data: dataString,
               cache: false,
               success: function(html) {
                    $('.city').html(html);
               } 
            });
       });
    });
```

I think, the error occurs when calling the url: 'http://domain1/get_data.php' from domain1 to domain2. Has anybody got an idea, why this might happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery ajax cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX calls must conform to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you cannot make plain AJAX calls to another domain.

There are, however, [workarounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Workarounds):

> To enable developers to, in a controlled manner, circumvent the Same Origin Policy, a number of 'hacks' such as using the Fragment Identifier, or the `window.name` property have been used to pass data between documents residing in different domains. With the HTML5 standard a method was formalized for this: the `postMessage` interface, which is only available on recent browsers. JSONP and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing can also be used to enable AJAX-like calls to other domains.[2]
>
> For supporting older browsers, the JavaScript library easyXDM can be used to provide a unified API for the `postMessage` interface as well as a number of hacks used to allow Cross Domain Messaging (XDM).

Answer (score 1):

Another way-

1. do an AJAX call to another_file.php file (which is in same domain)
2. from another_file.php; do a **[CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php)** request to the other domain and get response

Here is a simple **[CURL example](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

All AJAX calls must comply with the same origin rule. This rule stops AJAX from calling to another domain.

The facts:

> In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept
>   for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as
>   JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with
>   no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and
>   properties across pages on different sites.
>
> This mechanism bears a particular significance for modern web
>   applications that extensively depend on HTTP cookies to maintain
>   authenticated user sessions, as servers act based on the HTTP cookie
>   information to reveal sensitive information or take state-changing
>   actions. A strict separation between content provided by unrelated
>   sites must be maintained on client side to prevent the loss of data
>   confidentiality or integrity.

History:

> The concept of same origin policy dates back to Netscape Navigator
>   2.0. Close derivatives of the original design are used in all current browsers and are often extended to define roughly compatible security
>   boundaries for other web scripting languages, such as Adobe Flash, or
>   for mechanisms other than direct DOM manipulation, such as
>   XMLHttpRequest.

See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for more information.

An alternative method is by calling a PHP file (on your domain) with AJAX. Then perform a cURL call. See [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for more information. And [here's a simple example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)